# When should numbers used to derive RSA private key have leading `00`?

Tags: javascript, base64, rsa, asn.1, der

Given an RSA private key...

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBOgIBAAJBAMpZrx0gTluJEu6+fop1e60lwbnlBD6kHvoRx85GBhUgD8SQknjc
LcU2qqM/pV9ZX8MV8x49h2mzrmRyH7kDmpcCAwEAAQJAYf2GYMt5Rrids4IKk5CL
IPFs3FH8eT1PRvh/UvP0FBwDMZu/Q4m+3PNTM3ARQhFuCvWgCalMmZkyVx0HYRLe
4QIhAOaaQm+b/bSoHqolvVTcyfBL09rrLFZhgGkETX3R6cVRAiEA4KLdUm97YBxP
T6/jkn/P7K8SUWEO9o9u8Bif1UKQB2cCIETqoSQ92EqfW9q5wKWV/nvkDYKFehCu
vvOjp40MqPKhAiA2sPBZpbLQD5Rvvk8V1/Bzm5xGG+9csEc+RYCEl5QheQIhAKgi
Xb3zY9lqtpX/mgTIrW6RPB3GocviJOibqtpfNxRU
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Unarmoured, and base64 decoded gives...

```
30 82 01 3a 02 01 00 02 41 00 ca 59 af 1d 20 4e 5b 89 12 ee be 7e 8a 75 7b ad 25 c1 b9 e5 04 3e 
a4 1e fa 11 c7 ce 46 06 15 20 0f c4 90 92 78 dc 2d c5 36 aa a3 3f a5 5f 59 5f c3 15 f3 1e 3d 87 
69 b3 ae 64 72 1f b9 03 9a 97 02 03 01 00 01 02 40 61 fd 86 60 cb 79 46 b8 9d b3 82 0a 93 90 8b 
20 f1 6c dc 51 fc 79 3d 4f 46 f8 7f 52 f3 f4 14 1c 03 31 9b bf 43 89 be dc f3 53 33 70 11 42 11 
6e 0a f5 a0 09 a9 4c 99 99 32 57 1d 07 61 12 de e1 02 21 00 e6 9a 42 6f 9b fd b4 a8 1e aa 25 bd 
54 dc c9 f0 4b d3 da eb 2c 56 61 80 69 04 4d 7d d1 e9 c5 51 02 21 00 e0 a2 dd 52 6f 7b 60 1c 4f 
4f af e3 92 7f cf ec af 12 51 61 0e f6 8f 6e f0 18 9f d5 42 90 07 67 02 20 44 ea a1 24 3d d8 4a 
9f 5b da b9 c0 a5 95 fe 7b e4 0d 82 85 7a 10 ae be f3 a3 a7 8d 0c a8 f2 a1 02 20 36 b0 f0 59 a5 
b2 d0 0f 94 6f be 4f 15 d7 f0 73 9b 9c 46 1b ef 5c b0 47 3e 45 80 84 97 94 21 79 02 21 00 a8 22 
5d bd f3 63 d9 6a b6 95 ff 9a 04 c8 ad 6e 91 3c 1d c6 a1 cb e2 24 e8 9b aa da 5f 37 14 54
```

I extracted all the numbers from it, into an array...

```
[ '00',
  '00ca59af1d204e5b8912eebe7e8a757bad25c1b9e5043ea41efa11c7ce460615200fc4909278dc2dc536aaa33fa55f595fc315f31e3d8769b3ae64721fb9039a97',
  '010001',
  '61fd8660cb7946b89db3820a93908b20f16cdc51fc793d4f46f87f52f3f4141c03319bbf4389bedcf35333701142116e0af5a009a94c999932571d076112dee1',
  '00e69a426f9bfdb4a81eaa25bd54dcc9f04bd3daeb2c56618069044d7dd1e9c551',
  '00e0a2dd526f7b601c4f4fafe3927fcfecaf1251610ef68f6ef0189fd542900767',
  '44eaa1243dd84a9f5bdab9c0a595fe7be40d82857a10aebef3a3a78d0ca8f2a1',
  '36b0f059a5b2d00f946fbe4f15d7f0739b9c461bef5cb0473e45808497942179',
  '00a8225dbdf363d96ab695ff9a04c8ad6e913c1dc6a1cbe224e89baada5f371454' 
]
```

What I don't understand is...

#### 1. Why some of the extracted values have leading `00` and some don't?

#### 2. What is the purpose of the first value (`00`)? It seems redundant to me.

The reason I want to know, is I want to generate RSA keys in javascript. I am generating the numbers required, but I don't know when they should have leading `00`s.

***EDIT***

Also, I don't quite understand the first part of the whole thing...

```
30 82 01 3a
```

I understand the `01 3a` is the length of the rest of the message, but I don't know what the `30 82` represents.

#### 3. What is the `30 82` at the start of the decoded key?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the answers are here: http://pumka.net/2009/12/19/reading-writing-and-converting-rsa-keys-in-pem-der-publickeyblob-and-privatekeyblob-formats/

1. Notice that many integer values in DER begin with a zero byte. That's because ASN.1 standard requires adding zero byte to the beginning of multi-byte integer if the first bit of it is set to 1.
2. *Upadated after @Gwyn's answer (http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html)* It is the version number, currently only to distinguish multi-prime from normal, but will also be used to distinguish between revisions of the RSA spec
3. From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648645(v=vs.85).aspx And: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648641(v=vs.85).aspx

> A SEQUENCE contains an ordered field of one or more types. It is
>   encoded into a TLV triplet that begins with a Tag byte of 0x30.
>
> ...
>
> If the SEQUENCE contains fewer than 128 bytes, the Length field of the
>   TLV triplet requires only one byte to specify the content length. If
>   it is more than 127 bytes, bit 7 of the Length field is set to 1 and
>   bits 6 through 0 specify the number of additional bytes used to
>   identify the content length.

### The Code...

Here is the javascript code, a bit rough, but a working proof of how to generate RSA keys, to be interoperable with OpenSSL using javascript, and an input of the required numbers for key generation...

```
function hex2b64(h) {
  var b64map="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
  var b64pad="=";

  var i;
  var c;
  var ret = "";
  for(i = 0; i+3 <= h.length; i+=3) {
    c = parseInt(h.substring(i,i+3),16);
    ret += b64map.charAt(c >> 6) + b64map.charAt(c & 63);
  }
  if(i+1 == h.length) {
    c = parseInt(h.substring(i,i+1),16);
    ret += b64map.charAt(c << 2);
  }
  else if(i+2 == h.length) {
    c = parseInt(h.substring(i,i+2),16);
    ret += b64map.charAt(c >> 2) + b64map.charAt((c & 3) << 4);
  }
  while((ret.length & 3) > 0) ret += b64pad;
  return ret;
}

var private_key = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"+
"MIIBOgIBAAJBAMpZrx0gTluJEu6+fop1e60lwbnlBD6kHvoRx85GBhUgD8SQknjc\n"+
"LcU2qqM/pV9ZX8MV8x49h2mzrmRyH7kDmpcCAwEAAQJAYf2GYMt5Rrids4IKk5CL\n"+
"IPFs3FH8eT1PRvh/UvP0FBwDMZu/Q4m+3PNTM3ARQhFuCvWgCalMmZkyVx0HYRLe\n"+
"4QIhAOaaQm+b/bSoHqolvVTcyfBL09rrLFZhgGkETX3R6cVRAiEA4KLdUm97YBxP\n"+
"T6/jkn/P7K8SUWEO9o9u8Bif1UKQB2cCIETqoSQ92EqfW9q5wKWV/nvkDYKFehCu\n"+
"vvOjp40MqPKhAiA2sPBZpbLQD5Rvvk8V1/Bzm5xGG+9csEc+RYCEl5QheQIhAKgi\n"+
"Xb3zY9lqtpX/mgTIrW6RPB3GocviJOibqtpfNxRU\n"+
"-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

// these numbers have been extracted from the given RSA private key
numbers = ['00',
  'ca59af1d204e5b8912eebe7e8a757bad25c1b9e5043ea41efa11c7ce460615200fc4909278dc2dc536aaa33fa55f595fc315f31e3d8769b3ae64721fb9039a97',
  '010001',
  '61fd8660cb7946b89db3820a93908b20f16cdc51fc793d4f46f87f52f3f4141c03319bbf4389bedcf35333701142116e0af5a009a94c999932571d076112dee1',
  'e69a426f9bfdb4a81eaa25bd54dcc9f04bd3daeb2c56618069044d7dd1e9c551',
  'e0a2dd526f7b601c4f4fafe3927fcfecaf1251610ef68f6ef0189fd542900767',
  '44eaa1243dd84a9f5bdab9c0a595fe7be40d82857a10aebef3a3a78d0ca8f2a1',
  '36b0f059a5b2d00f946fbe4f15d7f0739b9c461bef5cb0473e45808497942179',
  'a8225dbdf363d96ab695ff9a04c8ad6e913c1dc6a1cbe224e89baada5f371454' ]

var data = ""

// loop through all the numbers
for(i in numbers){
  var item = numbers[i]

  // if the first binary bit is 1 (if the first hex pair is greater than 127)
  // add a `00` prefix, as ASN1 demands
  if(parseInt(item.match(/^../),16) > 127){ item = "00"+item }

  // calculate the length
  var len = ("0"+(item.length/2).toString(16)).replace(/.(..)/,"$1")

  // build data string, the `02` is ASN1 code for string
  data += "02"+len+item

  // can check all the input data here
  // console.log("02", len, item)
}

// calculate the length of all the data
var datalen = (data.length/2).toString(16)
// add leading `0` if required to ensure hex pairs
if(datalen.length % 2 == 1){ datalen = "0"+datalen }

// set the extra bits to define the length if required, or make it empty
var exlen = parseInt(datalen,16) >= 128 ? (datalen.length/2 + 128).toString(16) : ''

// create the full data string
var full_data = "30"+exlen+datalen+data

// encode the data
var encoded = hex2b64(full_data)

// split it into lines no longer than 64 characters
var lines = encoded.match(/.{1,64}/g)

// add the armour
lines.unshift("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----")
lines.push("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----")

// join it all together
var generated_key = lines.join("\n")

// check if the generated key matches the expected key
console.log(generated_key == private_key)
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind, but I embellished your answer to point [2].

Comment: @DuncanJones question 2 was actually not about the padding, but the first, seemingly redundant `00` extracted from the array of numbers. Your points, good as they are, belong actually on the tail end of question 1.

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer 2, as the others have been addressed, the first 00 is a version field. Use the ASN.1 decoder [here](http://lapo.it/asn1js/) to decode the Base64 or hex to show a SEQUENCE of 9 INTEGERS. You need to check the [specs](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/pkcs/files/h11300-wp-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard.pdf) (See A.1.2) to see what they are, although while not definitive, Wikipedia has some info [here](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Keys_and_Formats#RSA_PrivateKey)

Comment: Thanks, that answers all my questions then!